# Differential equation: $\ddot{y}(x) + \alpha\dot{y}^2(x) + \beta y(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am interested in finding an approximate solution for this differential equation, since the exact analytic solution seems to not exist. I tried with Mathematica and it spits out nothing.

$$\ddot{y}(x) + \alpha\dot{y}^2(x) + \beta y(x) = 0 ~~~~~~~ (\alpha, \beta) > 0$$

Clearly, I don't want an approximate solution like "let's cut one of the three terms". I was thinking about a good ansatz, but I found nothing really good. Also I got stuck while trying

$$y(x) = A(x)\ e^{-kt}$$

Sounds a really "simple" problem but maybe it's not. Any idea?

Comment: Look at the simpler equation $y'' + (y') ^2 + y = 0$ -  I mean,  the solutions might differ a bit,  but if a solution exists to that then your equation could likely be extrapolated.  WA can't solve the simpler one either,  but I haven't checked mathematica with it (mobile).  What context did you find this problem in?

Comment: Well, first you get rid of $\beta$ by changing the variable $x \rightarrow \frac{x}{\sqrt{\beta}}$

Comment: It would be really helpful to know if one of the terms is much smaller than the others. If, for example, second term is small, you will get a perturbed harmonic oscillator (with 'velocity' term)

Comment: Wait, what is your variable? $x$ or $t$. Your $y$ only depends on $x$, yet there is $t$ in your ansatz for some reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to expand upon Brevan Ellefsen's comment and my comments a little.

I assume that dots in OP's case mean $x$ derivative, since $y(x)$ depends only on $x$. Then we can easily get rid of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+\alpha \left(\frac{d y}{dx} \right)^2+\beta y=0
$$

Replacing:

$$
x \rightarrow \frac{x}{\sqrt{ \beta }}~~~~~y \rightarrow \alpha y
$$

We will get.

$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{d y}{dx} \right)^2+y=0
$$

[Here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0344.pdf) it's recommended to make a replacement:

$$
w(y)=\left(\frac{d y}{dx} \right)^2
$$

Then:

$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=\frac{d \sqrt{w}}{dx}=\frac{d \sqrt{w}}{dy} \sqrt{w}=\frac{d w}{2dy}
$$

The equation transforms to:

$$
\frac{d w}{dy}+2 w+2 y=0
$$

We only need to solve two first order ODEs. The solution for $w$ can be found easily (I used Wolframalpha):

$$
w(y)=C_1 e^{-2y}-y+\frac{1}{2}
$$

Then we need to solve first order nonlinear equation:

$$
\left(\frac{d y}{dx} \right)^2=C_1 e^{-2y}-y+\frac{1}{2}
$$

$$
\frac{d y}{dx}=\pm \sqrt{C_1 e^{-2y}-y+\frac{1}{2}}
$$

I suggest a simple numerical scheme. Also, since this equation is fully separable, we can try to approximate the integral instead.

For $C_1=0$ this ODE is exactly solvable.

$$
y=\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{x}{2}+C_2 \right)^2
$$

This is the exact partial solution of the original equation, which can be checked by direct substitution.

Or, alternatively if $|C_1|>>1$ and also much larger than maximum value for $y$, we can set $c_1=\sqrt{C_1}$ and get:

$$
\frac{d y}{dx} \approx \pm c_1 e^{-y}
$$

$$
y \approx \ln (|c_3 x|)
$$

This is a solution of the original equation without the third term (or with $\beta \rightarrow 0$).

And this is the answer to OP's confusion - since $y(x)$ can be approximated by $\ln(x)$ it's hardly surprising that their exponential ansatz did not fit well.

---

Some further ramblings:

> As for the best way to approximate the solution - it heavily depends on the context - if it was a simple pendulum in air for example, then you have harmonic oscillator motion with resistance proportional to velocity squared, and the second term can be interpreted as perturbation. However, since $\alpha$ is positive, it's apparently some other case. There is also the case of nonlinear Schrodinger, and there is a number of methods developed to solve this problem also.

My point is - there can be no 'general' approximate solutions, the appropriate approximation depends on the context of the original problem.