# Methods to approach the non-linear bvp $y''(x) - \lambda e^{y(x)} - \alpha=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation, nonlinear-system

I am searching for (semi)-analytical methods to approach the following non-linear boundary value problem

\begin{align*}
y''(x) - \lambda e^{y(x)} - \alpha&=0, \qquad \lambda,\alpha>0 \\
y(0)=y(1)=0 
\end{align*}
I am particularly interested in the case where $\lambda$ is large. I believe an explicit analytic solution does not exist. I can find an implicit solution by reducing the order via $y'(x) = \omega(y(x)) = \pm\sqrt{\lambda e^{y}+\alpha y+c_1}$ where $c_1$ is an integration constant, but it would be helpful to have an explicit approximation.

I have tried approaching the problem with the Adomian decomposition, but since in the end I am interested on large values of $\lambda$, the approximation (a polynomial proportional to $\lambda$) does not seem to converge well to the solution.

I am not sure if this helps, but the related problem with $\alpha=0$  (a.k.a Liouville problem) can be solved exactly by
\begin{align*}
y_{\alpha=0}(x) = 2\log\left[\frac{\cos{\frac{\theta}{4}}}{\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)\right)}\right]
\end{align*}
where the parameter $\lambda$ is related to $\theta$ via the equation $\theta = \sqrt{2\lambda} \cos{\frac{\theta}{4}}$. Here $\theta=2\pi$ corresponds to the asymptotic limit of interest $\lambda \to \infty$. Related to my remark above, $y_{\alpha=0}(x)$ reaches its maximum at $x=1/2$ where $y_{\alpha=0}(1/2)=2\log{\cos{\frac{\theta}{4}}}$, diverging logarithmically as $\theta\to2\pi$, so an approximation of $y_{\alpha=0}$ given by a power series proportional to $\lambda$ diverges faster.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any information on $\alpha$? Perhaps you can expand the solution in terms of this parameter ($y = y_0 + \alpha y_1 + \alpha^2 y_2 + \ldots $), given that for $\alpha = 0$ the solution $y_0$ is known.

Comment: @Dmoreno, thank you for the suggestion! I tried such a perturbative approach but I was searching for some method that eventually would allow to study $\alpha$ of the order of $\lambda$ (large).

Comment: What do you want exactly ? An asymptotic study when $\lambda$ is large ? Or something else ?

Comment: @M.LTA, any analytical approximation that capture the behaviour of the solution at large $\lambda$.

I have been vague because when consulting the literature on non-linear odes there is a plethora of different methods.

Comment: Related (this equation with $\lambda=-1$ and $\alpha=0$) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2659911/269624

Comment: Another related equation (see the implicit solution in this answer) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1648495/269624