# Trying to use Matlab to find Numerical Solution to $u''(x)+e^{u(x)}=0, u(0)=0, u(1)=0$ - Newton's method

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am trying to use Matlab to find Numerical Solution to $u''(x)+e^{u(x)}=0, u(0)=0, u(1)=0$. I can't get my code to work out. I was hoping you could help me. I have added citations to my code to explain what is going on. My confusion is that I am getting a lot of different "solution" graphs output. They change each time I run it. This doesn't seem right to me. Also, the boundary conditions are not portrayed on the graphed "solution".

For $G=\frac{1}{h^2}(u_{j-1}-2u_j+u_{j+1})+N(u_j)$ where $N(u_j)$ is the $e^{u(x)}$ nonlinear part, and for J being the Jacobian, I am trying to follow this procedure: Solve for delta, $$J(U^{(k)})\delta = -G(U^{(k)})$$
Then set $$U^{(k+1)}=U^{(k)}+\delta$$
Test for accuracy and repeat if necessary epsilon isn't reached.  Thank you for any help you can give.

Note: I think my initial guess should be this due to boundary conditions. 
Uk = [0 10*randn(1, m2-2) 0]'
But this doesn't converge.

This Uk leads to convergence at least...
Uk = rand(m2,1);

```
ax = 0;
bx = 1;
sigma = 0;   % Dirichlet boundary condition at ax
beta = 0;     % Dirichlet boundary condtion at bx
lambda = 1;
f = @(x) 0*x;  % right hand side function
epsilon = 0.01;
count = 1;
m1vals = 40;
m2= m1vals+1;
m1 = m1vals;
m = m1 - 1;                 % number of interior grid points
%Uk = [0 10*randn(1, m2-2) 0]'
%This Uk leads to convergence at least.
Uk = rand(m2,1);
Uk1=Uk;
h=0.01;
N = @(u) lambda*exp(u);
% set grid points:  
gridchoice = 'uniform';   
x = xgrid(ax,bx,m,gridchoice); 

while norm(Uk1-Uk) > epsilon || count ==1
    norm(Uk1-Uk) %check norm and print
    if count ~= 1 %only after first iteration
        Uk=Uk1;
    end
    %Part of J with -2 on main and 1 on off digaonals
    Jpart = (1/h^2)*(diag(-2*ones(m2,1),0)+diag(ones(m2-1,1),1)+diag(ones(m2-1,1),-1));
    %Create N' part of Jacobian
    %addJ is an estimate of u'(x) since we need u'(x)*lambda*exp(u(x))
    addJ = spalloc(m2,m2,3*m2);
    addJ(1,1:3) = fdcoeffF(1, x(1), x(1:3)); 
    for i=2:m1
         addJ(i,i-1:i+1) = fdcoeffF(1, x(i), x((i-1):(i+1)));
    end
    addJ(m2,m:m2) = fdcoeffF(1,x(m2),x(m:m2)); 
    %computes u'(x)*lambda*exp(u(x)) at Uk.
    J2 = diag(addJ*Uk,0)*N(Uk);   %addJ*Uk is an estimate of u'(x) at Uk points.
    J=Jpart+diag(J2,0); %put all together

      % set up matrix G = u''+N
      Gpart = spalloc(m2,m2,3*m2);   % initialize to zero matrix
      % first row for Dirichlet BC at ax:
      Gpart(1,1:3) = fdcoeffF(0, x(1), x(1:3)); 
      % interior rows:
      for i=2:m1
         Gpart(i,i-1:i+1) = fdcoeffF(2, x(i), x((i-1):(i+1)));
      end
      % last row for Dirichlet BC at bx:
      Gpart(m2,m:m2) = fdcoeffF(0,x(m2),x(m:m2)); 
      %Set up for J(Uk)delta=-G(Uk) 
      Gall=Gpart+diag(N(Uk),0); 
      Gans=-Gall*Uk; %evaluate G(Uk)
Delta = J\Gans;
Uk1 = Uk + Delta;
count = count + 1;  
end



  clf
  plot(x,Uk1,'o')  % plot computed solution
  title(sprintf('Computed solution with %i grid points',m2));
```

Comment: Can you provide plots of your solution?

Comment: @P.Siehr, what do you think of my exact solution? Is it normal for nonlinear boundary value problem to have several solutions? Uniqueness works only for Cauchy problems?

Comment: @YuriyS . My comment refers to OPs `But this doesn't converge.` Pictures are often useful when it comes to ODE-code. About uniqueness: I am not an expert for ODEs, so I don't know if it is `normal`. But even linear BVPs may have several solutions. Take e.g. $u'' + u = 0$ in $I=[0,π]$. Solution: $u(t)=a\sin(t) + b\cos(t)$.  Then it is: $$ u(0)=u(π)=0  \qquad \text{∞ solutions} \\ u(0)=0, u(π)=1  \qquad \text{no solution} \\ u(0)=u(π), u'(0)=u'(π)  \qquad \text{unique solution}.$$ Still there are conditions under which the BVP has a (theoretically) unique solution.

Comment: @P. Siehr I can add graphs ya. The problem is that each time I run it it is very different. Due to solutions posted, I can see I am not getting the right answer. :/

Comment: Well, that is exaclty the information that was missing in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had trouble following your code, but it seemed that you were taking
$$\frac d{dx}e^{U_k}=e^{U_k}\frac{dU_k}{dx}$$
Which is wrongheaded because you really need
$$\frac d{dU_j}e^{U_i}=e^{U_i}\delta_{ij}$$
Writing a simpleminded code with that change I was able to reproduce [Yuriy S](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269624/yuriy-s)'s analytical results.

```
% nonlinear.m

clear all;
close all;
m = 200;
h = 1/(m+1);
G0 = (diag(ones(m-1,1),-1)-2*diag(ones(m,1),0)+diag(ones(m-1,1),1))/h^2;
x = [1:m]/(m+1);
iarray = [1 20];
for k = 1:length(iarray),
    Uk = iarray(k)*x.*(1-x);
    err = ones(size(Uk));
    while norm(err) > 1.0e-6,
        G = G0*Uk'+exp(Uk)';
        J = G0+diag(exp(Uk));
        err = (J\G)';
        Uk = Uk-err;
    end
    U(k,:) = Uk';
end
plot([0 x 1],[0 U(1,:) 0],[0 x 1],[0 U(2,:) 0]);
```

[image: Graphs of the two solutions]

Comment: Thank you so very much. I see now. I was differentiating with respect to x and that wasn't right. Much appreciated

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 5):

Not related to your numerical algorithm (sorry, not my forte), but might be useful when checking the solutions. This equation is exactly solvable.

$$u''+e^u=0$$

Using inverse functions, we have for $x(u)$:

$$\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}=-\frac{x''}{x'^3}$$

Now the equation becomes:

$$x''-e^u x'^3=0$$

New function:

$$x'=y(u)$$

Now the equation becomes:

$$y'=e^u y^3$$

Integrating:

$$\frac{1}{y^2}=C_1 - 2e^u$$

$$y = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1-2e^u}}$$

Now returning to $x(u)$:

$$x'=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1-2e^u}}$$

$$x=\pm \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{C_1-2e^u}}+C_2$$

The integral has an exact form:

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{C_1-2e^u}}=- \frac{2}{\sqrt{C_1}} \tanh^{-1} \sqrt{1-\frac{2}{C_1} e^u}$$

So our solution is:

$$x=\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{C_1}} \tanh^{-1} \sqrt{1-\frac{2}{C_1} e^u}+C_2$$

Or:

$$\tanh^{-1} \sqrt{1-\frac{2}{C_1} e^u}= C_2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2} x$$

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{C_1} e^u}=\tanh \left( C_2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2} x\right)$$

$$1-\frac{2}{C_1} e^u=\tanh^2 \left( C_2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2} x\right)$$

$$e^u=\frac{C_1}{2} \left(1-\tanh^2 \left( C_2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2} x\right) \right)$$

> $$u= \log \left( \frac{C_1}{2} \left(1-\tanh^2 \left( C_2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2} x\right) \right) \right)$$

I have checked this solution by differentiating twice in wolfram alpha and it works.

Now we can try to substitute boundary conditions and get the values for the constants. From $u(0)=0$ we get:

$$C_1=\frac{2}{1- \tanh^2 C_2}$$

For the second constant we might have to solve the equation numerically. From $u(1)=0$ and the constant we just found we have:

$$1- \tanh^2 \left( C_2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2}\right)=1- \tanh^2 C_2$$

Since $C_1 \neq 0$, we can use the fact that $\tanh^2$ is even to write:

$$\frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2}-C_2=C_2$$

Or, substituting $C_1$:

$$4 C_2= \sqrt{\frac{2}{1- \tanh^2 C_2}}$$

Wolfram Alpha gives two numerical solutions:

$$C_2=2.7346756930305266999 \\ C_2 = 0.37929114976268859213$$

Now we can see how the solutions look (red the first choice for $C_2$, blue - the second choice):

[image]

Apparently, there's two solutions, both of which satisfy the boundary conditions. Which might be one of the problems with numerical algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely not what I’m getting. I appreciate this though as it will help me know when I do get it right.

Comment: @MathIsHard, yes indeed, it's always useful to have an exact solution to compare your numerical results to. I always test my algorithms on exactly solvable equations first

Comment: Excellent guidance for my version of the program.

Comment: @YuriyS Can you explain the first step where you introduce the inverse function? This is very cool!

Comment: @Rumplestillskin, see this link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation.

Comment: This is a cool trick. But does it only work in the case were you can write one specifically in terms of the other? E.g we can not use this trick for the DE $(u’’(x) + u(x))e^{u(x)}= f(u(x))$ for some function of $u$ that is given.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin, "you can write one specifically in terms of the other" - what in terms of what? I don't understand your question. By the way, in your example, you can introduce a new function $g(u)=f(u) e^{-u}-u$, then you will have $u''=g(u)$.